# remove all instances of a specific character ("y") from a list in python

Tags: python, list

```
c=['x', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '-', 'x', 'Y', '-', 'x', '-', 'x', 'x', 'x']

for x,element in enumerate(c):
    if element=="Y":
        c.pop(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[element for element in c if element !="Y"]
```